# Is there a way to nest options in a lightning-combobox?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I want to use the lightning-combobox to create a nested select list. Like this.

[image: Combbox Sections]

I can build it using Lightning Design System. But hoping there is an easier way to pass the options into the combobox. I've tried setting the options in the tag but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the following code in html markup

```
<label>
    Relate To
</label>
<lightning-base-combobox
         items={items}

></lightning-base-combobox>
```

and the following code in Javascript

```
get items() {
    return [{
    label: 'Group One',
    items: [{
        type: 'option-inline',
      text: 'Burlington Textiles Corp of America'
    }, {
      text: 'Dickenson pic',
      type: 'option-inline'
    }]
  }, {
    label: 'Group Two',
    items: [{
      text: 'Dickenson pic',
      type: 'option-inline' 
    }, {
      text: 'Edge Communications',
      type: 'option-inline'
    }]
  }];
}
```

You can try this in [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Os_8bhadU/1/edit).
[image]

Comment: @joshii Are you sure this doesn't work? Since it works for me, check it here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Os_8bhadU/1/edit

Comment: Sorry I deleted my earlier comment because I realized I didn't update my combobox to base-combobox. As already mentioned it doesn't deploy. I get an error "No MODULE named baseCombobox found".

Comment: ok, strange then that this works in playground but doesn't work in actual org. I think we should open a case with Salesforce to investigate this

Comment: I expected playground to have the same functionality as exposed to real Organization

Answer (score 0):

While this works in Playground, when it is deployed in Core Salesforce, access checks will get in the way.

Playground is not attached to an instance of Salesforce, it is a tool for learning language semantics. While this works in a Standalone LWC environment, it likely will not work when deployed.